# Django Rest Framework serializer update method does not save object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have overridden the update method for one of my serializers to call a model's method before saving the object. Like so:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [...]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.model_method()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

In my views, I am saving the serializer using `serializer.save()`, and of course setting it using `MyModelSerializer(instance, data=request.data)`. However, my instance is not being saved. Just removing the update method saves the instance, but does not call the `model_method()` obviously. How can I fix this issue? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does the `model_method` do? Does it modify any attributes of the instance?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what it does

Comment: Did you try returning `super()` call at the end ie after 1st line instead of calling `instance.save()`.

Comment: Could you write that out as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call `super()` method after `instance.model_method()` is called so as to save the data on the updated instance.

The problem with the approach mentioned above in the question is that `validated_data` is not used anywhere to `save()` which leaves the instance as is.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [...]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.model_method() # call model method for instance level computation

        # call super to now save modified instance along with the validated data
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```