# PATCH method not working in Django ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, patch, django-serializer

I'm having trouble in using **patch** method inside a ModelViewSet for my custom User model.
Here is the code:

**views.py**

```
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
    class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'head', 'delete']
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id',
              'email',
              'password',
              'is_active',
              'is_staff',
              'is_admin')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True},
                    'is_active': {'default': True},
                    'is_staff': {'default': False},
                    'is_admin': {'default': False}}

def create(self, validated_data):
    self.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    if validated_data['is_admin']:
        validated_data['is_staff'] = True
    user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
    return user

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email')
    instance.is_active = validated_data.get('is_active')
    instance.is_staff = validated_data.get('is_staff')
    instance.is_admin = validated_data.get('is_admin')
    if instance.is_admin:
        instance.is_staff = True
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

I set a permission in order to allow only superuser to access this view. The problem comes when trying to perform a patch. For example, if I try to change *is_staff* attribute to *False* of a User using Postman with PATCH and "http://localhost:8000/users/USER_ID", I get the following error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, pbkdf2_sha256$180000$6jePqBspO6xK$tCQ9zZk1uOdJD2F7L9BQRFFDbz1GXJ..., 2020-04-18 20:02:57.052639+00, null, t, t, t).

It seems like django asks me to provide every single field fo User model (*email*, *is_active*, *is_staff*, *is_admin*), which it doesn't make sense in my opinion givien that it's a PATCH request.
To overcome the issue, I've modified the *update* method of my **UserSerializer** like that:

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if validated_data.get('email') is not None:
            instance.email = validated_data.get('email')
        if validated_data.get('is_active') is not None:
            instance.is_active = validated_data.get('is_active')
        if validated_data.get('is_staff') is not None:
            instance.is_staff = validated_data.get('is_staff')
        if validated_data.get('is_admin') is not None:
            instance.is_admin = validated_data.get('is_admin')
        if instance.is_admin:
            instance.is_staff = True
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

It works now, but I'd like to know whether this is a good solution. In my opinion, it is not a "canonical" way for solving the problem. I've also tried to override **partial_update** method (following others StackOverflow's answers) inside my UserViewSet, with no results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a PATCH request using DJANGO REST framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148039/how-to-make-a-patch-request-using-django-rest-framework)

Comment: the problem I think in route and URL, not view, you have to remove http_method_name

Answer (score 0):

I've found very useful this previous post [django-rest-framework-serializer-update-method-does-not-save-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774022/django-rest-framework-serializer-update-method-does-not-save-object)
The problem was in the serializer. I've changed the overwritten **update** method inside my **UserSerializer** and now PATCH works

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    if validated_data.get('is_admin'):
        validated_data['is_staff'] = True
    return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

NOTE: no need to override any method in the view, just add *'patch'* to *http_method_names* list